# Does the column space of a matrix have the same dimension of a column space of that matrix in echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have two matrices $A$, $B$ that are row-equivalent. Matrix $B$ is in echelon form. Would $\operatorname{Col}(A)$ and $\operatorname{Col}(B)$ have the same dimension? I know that the contents of the column spaces themselves aren't always the same, but would the dimensions still be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if $A$ and $B$ are row-equivalent then their columns spaces have the same dimension (i.e. rank).

This is because $A$ and $B$ have the same null space. To see this, note that there is an invertible matrix $M$ such that $B = MA$. Suppose $x$ is in the null space of $A$. Then $Bx = MAx = M(Ax) = 0$, so $x$ is in the null space of $B$. Conversely, if $x$ is in the null space of $B$, then $Bx = 0$, hence $MAx = 0$. But $M$ is invertible, so this implies $Ax = M^{-1}0 = 0$, so $x$ is in the null space of $A$.

Now let $n$ denote the number of columns of $A$ (and hence also of $B$). The [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) tells us that
$$\dim(\operatorname{col}(A)) + \dim(\operatorname{null}(A)) = n$$
and
$$\dim(\operatorname{col}(B)) + \dim(\operatorname{null}(B)) = n$$
Since $\dim(\operatorname{null}(A)) = \dim(\operatorname{null}(B))$, this means that $\dim(\operatorname{col}(A)) = \dim(\operatorname{col}(B))$.